# Looking for layout library with clean separation between model and rendering

Tags: javascript, python, layout, graphics, standards

I'll use the term "box model" generically to refer to any data model designed to represent the graphical layout of "rectangular containers" (aka "boxes"), and to perform related computations (e.g. computing the positions of individual boxes upon the resizing of an enclosing box).  ([Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) one example of such a model.)

The essence of my question is this:

> I am looking for an implementation of a "box model" with the following properties, roughly *in order of importance*:
>
> 1. it should maintain a clean separation between the *modeling* of layout information (e.g. dimensions, margins, padding, containment relationships, etc.), and the rendering of this information in some specific device (e.g. web browser, PostScript, X11, etc.);
> 2. it should faithfully implement some "standard" box model (e.g., [w3's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)), or, short of that, at least have a substantial enough adoption base to be a credible candidate for the title of "de facto standard";
> 3. preferably it should be written in Python (second choice: JavaScript; third choice: anything else!).

I realize that if there is something out there that satisfies these criteria, it is very unlikely that it will be in isolation.  Most likely it will be a component of a larger system.  This is OK.

<sub>NB: IMO, the remainder of this post does not contain any information required to answer the question above.  *I include this additional content only for the benefit those who may want to know where this question is coming from, before answering it.*  It is *not* intended, however, as fodder for discussion.  Please limit any responses to it to the comments section.  In any case, if, contrary to my estimation, this supplementary content is deemed inappropriate for SO, please let me know and I'll be more than happy to delete it.</sub>

---

A succinct (though probably a bit opaque) statement of the motivation behind this question would be something like this:

> to *minimize* the amount of "cognitive dissonance" added by the library that I am implementing at the moment.

In somewhat more detail, the "cognitive dissonance" I'm referring to is that which gets introduced by every new piece of software that models a well-established problem domain in a way that is "basically equivalent but not identical" to any other existing software operating in the same problem domain.  Such "cognitive dissonance" includes new terminology for established concepts, or new meanings of established terms, new conventions, etc.

The obvious way to minimize such cognitive dissonance is stick to the principle of adopting the terminology and conventions of some pre-existing standard data model.  Of course, this strategy can succeed only if there *is* such a standard data model, and then only in proportion to its prevalence.  (In my experience at least, widely adopted data models are relatively rare, and this is why my aim is only to "minimize", rather than altogether "avoid", the cognitive dissonance caused by my library-in-the-making.)

More specifically, I'm working on a small in-house library to facilitate the problem of ***abstractly encoding, and computing with,*** layout information.

This library is still extremely simple, but I already find myself having to make largely arbitrary choices on matters of nomenclature, conventions, and overall structure.  For example, in Python:

```
# EXAMPLE 1

from __future__ import division

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

def make_box(width, height, aspect_ratio=None):
    if aspect_ratio is not None:
        w = height * aspect_ratio
        if w < width:
            width = w
        else:
            height = width / aspect_ratio
    return Box(width, height)
```

This function creates the largest `Box` object that will *fit* within a surrounding box having the specified width and height, and will have the aspect ratio `aspect_ratio`, if specified.

(NOTE: all the code in this post is meant only by way of illustration, and not as examples of production-grade code.  Hence: no error-checking, no performance optimizations, no handling of round-off errors, etc.)

One thing to note is that, even in this small toy example, I have already introduced several terms and conventions that may or may not conform with "standard practice", including:

1. the *choice* of terms "box", "width", "height", and "aspect_ratio" (as opposed to, say, "frame", "delta_x", "delta_y", and "proportion");
2. the *definition* of "aspect ratio" as the ratio `width/height` (as opposed to the ratio `height/width`);
3. the "default ordering" of "width" and "height" in expressions such as `Box(50, 100)`;
4. the policy for handling cases where the specified `aspect_ratio` and the specified combination of `width` and `height` disagree (namely: interpret the `width` and `height` as *maximal*, as opposed to, e.g., *minimal*, allowable values).

Arguably, the problem is not limited to terminology, or to simple conventions such as the default ordering of arguments, but extends also to design decisions that are equally a matter of convention, even if they have much broader scope.

To illustrate this point, imagine enhancing the model with a `Padding` class, and changing the `make_box` function so that instead of returning a `Box` object that is possibly smaller than the size specified by the `width` and `height` arguments, it always returns a `Box` having exactly those dimensions, but also including a `padding` attribute encoding any discrepancy between the specified `aspect_ratio`, and the specified `width` and `height`.  Furthermore, when there is such a discrepancy, split the left over space equally between both sides of the box (i.e. make the resulting padding symmetrical).  (See `EXAMPLE 2` below for a code rendition of this description.)

This small enhancement by itself introduces yet another bunch of terms and conventions, but I want to focus on the fact that this small enhancement already points to an elaboration of the model, to include one additional type of object (a "padding"), and along with it a particular (though largely arbitrary) relationship between this new type of object, and the pre-existing ones (notably, "boxes").  In other word, this small enhancement really *implies* an expansion of the model that affects the rest of the library, *globally*.  I would like my library to conform to such "global" structural conventions as well, and not just to smaller-scope ones, such as default orderings, and the like.

Granted, some of these design decisions will just happen to agree perfectly, or closely enough, with whatever may be considered "standard".  Furthermore, each of those that deviate from this standard will entail only a small cognitive burden on its prospective users.  After all, if instead of "box" the standard term were, say, "frame", it would not be hugely taxing to those reading my library's (eventual) documentation to mentally substitute "frame" for every mention of "box".  Nevertheless, *in the aggregate*, and especially in a "cognitive universe" that already includes many other similar libraries (and that the typical programmer must work with), each of them adding its own minor deviations from convention, the effect does become burdensome.  These shifting conventions hamper learning about new software, and one particularly tangible manifestation of this is in the form of bugs, some of which can be quite difficult to spot.

As I've already stated, it is not realistic to hope that one could eliminate all such cognitive dissonance.  For one thing, there is no standard.  The best one can hope for is to confuse the fewest number of users, but even then this number will still be substantial.  Moreover, there are situations in which the *long-term* benefits (as opposed to the programmer's short-term convenience) of consciously adopting some non-standard convention or terminology do legitimately justify the additional cognitive dissonance incurred in.  That said, I suspect that such cases are quite rare.

---

```
# EXAMPLE 2

from __future__ import division

class Padding(object):
    def __init__(self, top=0, right=0, bottom=0, left=0):
        self.top = top
        self.right = right
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.left = left

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height, padding=Padding()):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.padding = padding

def make_box(width, height, aspect_ratio=None):
    if aspect_ratio is None:
        return Box(width, height)
    else:
        w = height * aspect_ratio
        if w < width:
            p = (width - w)/2
            padding = Padding(left=p, right=p)
        else:
            h = width / aspect_ratio
            p = (height - h)/2
            padding = Padding(top=p, bottom=p)
        return Box(width, height, padding)
```

Comment: So what it comes down to, is you want to use something like CSS in an application?

Comment: gtk has a way to store the interface in ui files. There's also ways to embed webkit in an application.

Comment: from the relevant off-topic sub-option: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I suspect this question would be much better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.  It's not a _bad_ question, just not on-topic for SO.

Comment: @tcaswell: thanks for your comments; I'd be happy to delete the question, and maybe repost it in Programmers SE, though I think it's too late now, since it already received a reply.

Comment: Flag it for a moderator and ask them to move it.

Comment: @tcaswell: thanks for the suggestion; I did so, although afterwards I learned that this question will probably be off-topic there too; unfortunately, it seems that I cannot rescind a flag; IOW, a mess...

Comment: That is what moderators are for, cleaning up messes ;) (with in reason of course)

Comment: @kjo, Was my answer useful?

Comment: @plalx: yes it was.  i have been waiting to see if the thread gets moved...  but i probably should accept it and move on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I haven't took enough time to carefully read your post, but I am still not sure that I identified the question correctly?

However from what I understood, I think you might want to have a look at how Sencha designed their layout system for the ExtJS library.

Their idea is quite simple, but leads to an extremely easy-to-use, powerful and flexible layout system.

Basically, every [container](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container) can be used in conjonction with a [layout manager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Layout) which is responsible for rendering children components.

You can have a look at their [Layouts and Containers guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/layouts_and_containers).

Also you will be interested in their [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component) class which is basically the `Box` class you are trying to implement.